# Хорошая информация по ncurses

Tags: c++, linux, c, ncurses

Хочу выучить ncurses. Все, что я нашел, - hello world'ы.

Answer (score 2):

[NCURSES Programming HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/)

Answer (score 0):

Неплохой вводный раздел есть в книге Метью, Стоунс. Основы программирования в Linux.
Далее - очень хороший [HOWTO](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=ncurses%20programming%20howto%20pdf&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ibiblio.org%2Fpub%2FLinux%2Fdocs%2FHOWTO%2Fother-formats%2Fpdf%2FNCURSES-Programming-HOWTO.pdf&ei=03u6TqmiFdP64QT00MjsBw&usg=AFQjCNHoeFZ1JXXcwXZXdnSiYMT9WnjMPg&cad=rjt)